# Trying to compile example code from Octave's Standalone Programs example, getting segfault on first line

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, octave, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to learn how to embed Octave in my C++ code. When running the second example from [here](http://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Standalone-Programs.html), the code compiles fine, but when running the code, a segmentation fault appears in the first line, when trying to initialize the interpreter. I'm not extremely adept at C++ but even when looking it up I can't find any answers.

The original code had octave::feval instead of feval, that threw a different, namespace error, so I just got rid of that and added the parse.h in the includes. I doubt this is at all related to the issue but that is a modification I did do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>

int
main (void)
{
  // Create interpreter.

  octave::interpreter interpreter;

  try
    {
      int status = interpreter.execute ();

      if (status != 0)
        {
          std::cerr << "creating embedded Octave interpreter failed!"
                    << std::endl;
          return status;
        }

      octave_idx_type n = 2;
      octave_value_list in;

      for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
        in(i) = octave_value (5 * (i + 2));

      octave_value_list out = feval ("gcd", in, 1);

      if (out.length () > 0)
        std::cout << "GCD of ["
                  << in(0).int_value ()
                  << ", "
                  << in(1).int_value ()
                  << "] is " << out(0).int_value ()
                  << std::endl;
      else
        std::cout << "invalid\n";
    }
  catch (const octave::exit_exception& ex)
    {
      std::cerr << "Octave interpreter exited with status = "
                << ex.exit_status () << std::endl;
    }
  catch (const octave::execution_exception&)
    {
      std::cerr << "error encountered in Octave evaluator!" << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The actual output is supposed to be:

```
GCD of [10, 15] is 5
```

I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 with Octave 4.2.2

Comment: *the code compiles fine* -- I don't know why persons bring this up.  "Compiling fine" only means that there are no syntax errors, and that the linker found the requisite functions.  It has no bearing on whether the program will run correctly, whether the program does or does not have logical errors, etc.

Comment: The code compiles fine and also works on Cygwin and Octave 4.4.1 with output `GCD of [10, 15] is 5`. It also compiles fine with no warning using `octave::feval`

Comment: How do you compile your code? I can just guess that you are linking for a different ABI which could be the case if you have different versions of GNU Octave installed in parallel.

Comment: I use mkoctfile to compile the code but the real issue is the segfault. Im using gcc on an ubuntu 18 machine. If it compiles well on your machine, any ideas why mine is an issue? Running octave 4.4.2

Comment: “The real issue is the segfault”—No, this is the symptom. To find the real issue, the source of your problems, we need to know how you compiled the code. Also, getting an error over `octave::feval` is an important issue. Don’t gloss over that. What was the error? How is `feval` defined in your Octave header files? Is your Octave installed through the Ubuntu package manager?

Comment: the code was compiled using the following command: `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone main.cc -o embedded`, the error generated is: `‘feval’ is not a member of ‘octave’
       octave_value_list out = octave::feval ("gcd", in, 1);`. feval is not at all present in `octave.h` , but it is present `parse.h`. Octave is installed thru the Ubuntu package manager.

Comment: what does `mkoctfile --version` return on your system?

Comment: it returns `mkoctfile, version 4.2.2` which does not match the version I said I was running, but I think that was a mistake on my part, as when running `octave --version` I get `GNU Octave, version 4.2.2`. I updated the original question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation looked at is a different version than the version I have installed on my computer. I have 4.2, but I was looking at 4.4 docs, which has different code for the task I was trying to accomplish.